Lock in tantivy while searching
I am using an Actix server to support a total of 1000 transactions per second (TPS), with clients sending requests from 10 threads in parallel. Tantivy search queries from the index are typically taking around 4 milliseconds, though there are occasional spikes where the response time jumps to over 100 milliseconds, as shown in the logs below.
In single threaded client(no parallel requests) there is no spike observed.
No index writing is occurring during the search process; all documents were loaded into the index at startup.
Logs
Response total in logs means time taken for search.
esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 6 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:7] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 4 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:1] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 4 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:7] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 4 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:1] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 4 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:7] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 5 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:1] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 6 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:7] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 4 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:0] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 107 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:2] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 107 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:1] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 7 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:7] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 7 
2024-08-06 18:01:08 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:0] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 8 
2024-08-06 18:01:09 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:7] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 4 
2024-08-06 18:01:09 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:1] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 7 
2024-08-06 18:01:09 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:7] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 3 
2024-08-06 18:01:09 [actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:0] INFO - esme::handlers::submit_sm::src/handlers/submit_sm.rs:64 - Response  total : 6 

A sudden spike in Tantivy search time from 4 to 104 ms occurred.
This is my code:
use tantivy::schema::*;
use tantivy::{Index, IndexWriter, TantivyDocument};
use tantivy::query::QueryParser;
use tantivy::collector::TopDocs;
use std::sync::{Mutex, RwLock, Arc};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

pub struct MySearchEngine {
    indexes: RwLock<HashMap<String, Arc<SingleIndex>>>,
}

pub struct SingleIndex {
    index: Index,
    writer: Mutex<IndexWriter>,
}

impl SingleIndex {
    fn new() -> tantivy::Result<Self> {
        let mut schema_builder = Schema::builder();
        let _title = schema_builder.add_text_field("title", TEXT | STORED);
        let _body = schema_builder.add_text_field("body", TEXT | STORED);
        let schema = schema_builder.build();

        let index = Index::create_in_ram(schema.clone());
        let writer = index.writer(50_000_000)?;

        Ok(SingleIndex {
            index,
            writer: Mutex::new(writer),
        })
    }

    fn add_document(&self, title: &str, body: &str) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let mut writer = self.writer.lock().unwrap();
        let mut doc = tantivy::TantivyDocument::default();
        doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("title").unwrap(), title);
        doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("body").unwrap(), body);
        writer.add_document(doc);
        writer.commit()?;
        let duration = start.elapsed();
        Ok(duration)
    }
    fn add_documents(&self, documents: &Vec<(String, String)>) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let mut writer = self.writer.lock().unwrap();
        for (title, body) in documents {
            let mut doc = tantivy::TantivyDocument::default();
            doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("title").unwrap(), title);
            doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("body").unwrap(), body);
            writer.add_document(doc);
        }
        writer.commit()?;
        let duration = start.elapsed();
        Ok(duration)
    }
    fn search(&self, query_str: &str) -> tantivy::Result<(Duration, Vec<(f32, tantivy::TantivyDocument)>)> {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let reader = self.index.reader()?;
        let searcher = reader.searcher();

        let query_parser = QueryParser::for_index(&self.index, vec![
            self.index.schema().get_field("body").unwrap(),
        ]);
        let query = query_parser.parse_query(query_str)?;

        let top_docs = searcher.search(&query, &TopDocs::with_limit(10))?;
        let mut results = Vec::new();
        for (score, doc_address) in top_docs {
            let doc = searcher.doc(doc_address)?;
            results.push((score, doc));
        }
        let duration = start.elapsed();
        Ok((duration, results))
    }
}

impl MySearchEngine {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MySearchEngine {
            indexes: RwLock::new(HashMap::new()),
        }
    }

    fn get_or_create_index(&self, key: &str) -> tantivy::Result<Arc<SingleIndex>> {
        let mut indexes = self.indexes.write().unwrap();

        if let Some(index) = indexes.get(key) {
            return Ok(Arc::clone(index));
        }

        let index = SingleIndex::new()?;
        let index = Arc::new(index);
        indexes.insert(key.to_string(), Arc::clone(&index));
        Ok(index)
    }

    pub fn add_document(&self, key: &str, title: &str, body: &str) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let index = self.get_or_create_index(key)?;
        index.add_document(title, body)
    }
    pub fn add_documents(&self, key: &str, documents: &Vec<(String, String)>) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let index = self.get_or_create_index(key)?;
        index.add_documents(documents)
    }
    pub fn search(&self, key: &str, query_str: &str) -> tantivy::Result<(Duration, Vec<(f32, tantivy::TantivyDocument)>)> {
        let index = self.get_or_create_index(key)?;
        index.search(query_str)
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref SEARCH_ENGINE: Arc<MySearchEngine> = {
        let engine = MySearchEngine::new();
        Arc::new(engine)
    };
}


use std::ptr::null;
use actix_web::{post, web, Responder, HttpResponse};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use log::info;
use chrono::Utc;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use regex::Regex;
use tantivy::schema::Value;
use crate::tant::tantivy_lib::SEARCH_ENGINE;
use crate::utils::transaction_id::generate_transaction_id;

// Define data structures
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct SubmitSm {
    #[serde(default = "default_transaction_id")]
    pub transaction_id: i32,
    pub key: String,
    #[serde(default = "default_field2")]
    pub query: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct ResponseSm {
    pub timestamp: String, // Use String to store timestamp in ISO 8601 format
    pub transaction_id: i32,
    pub time_taken: u128,
    pub status: String,
    pub response: Vec<(f32, tantivy::TantivyDocument)>,
}

fn default_transaction_id() -> i32 {
    // Generate a unique transaction ID
    generate_transaction_id() // Use the function from the module
}

fn default_field2() -> String {
    "default query".to_string() // default value for query field
}

// Define the handler function
#[post("/esme/http_adapter")]
pub async fn http_adapter(item: web::Json<SubmitSm>) -> impl Responder {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let data: SubmitSm = item.into_inner();
    info!("Received POST request to /esme/http_adapter with data: {:?}", data);

    // Create the response with current timestamp and the transaction_id from SubmitSm
    let start1 = Instant::now();
    let search_engine = SEARCH_ENGINE.clone();
    let duration1 = start1.elapsed().as_millis();
    let (duration, results) = search_engine.search(&data.key, &data.query).unwrap(); // Destructure the tuple

    //for (score, doc) in &results {
       // info!("key: {:?}  = value: {:?}", doc.field_values().get(0).unwrap().value(), doc.field_values().get(1).unwrap().value().as_str().unwrap());
   // }
   // info!("Received POST results to : {:?}", results);
    let response = ResponseSm {
        timestamp: Utc::now().to_rfc3339(), // Get current UTC timestamp in RFC 3339 format
        transaction_id: data.transaction_id, // Include the transaction ID
        status: "Success".to_string(),
        time_taken: start.elapsed().as_millis(),
        response: results, // Directly use results without cloning
    };
    info!("Response  total : {:?} ", start.elapsed().as_millis());
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(response) // Return the response as JSON
}

here am getting lock
let start1 = Instant::now();
let reader = self.index.reader()?;
let duration2=start1.elapsed();

How do I fix this spike?

use tantivy::schema::*;
use tantivy::{Index, IndexWriter, TantivyDocument, IndexReader};
use tantivy::query::QueryParser;
use tantivy::collector::TopDocs;
use std::sync::{Mutex, RwLock, Arc};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

pub struct MySearchEngine {
    indexes: RwLock<HashMap<String, Arc<SingleIndex>>>,
}

pub struct SingleIndex {
    index: Index,
    writer: Mutex<IndexWriter>,
    reader: RwLock<IndexReader>,
}

impl SingleIndex {
    fn new() -> tantivy::Result<Self> {
        let mut schema_builder = Schema::builder();
        let _title = schema_builder.add_text_field("title", TEXT | STORED);
        let _body = schema_builder.add_text_field("body", TEXT | STORED);
        let schema = schema_builder.build();

        let index = Index::create_in_ram(schema.clone());
        let writer = index.writer(1024 * 1024 * 1024)?;
        let reader = index.reader()?;

        Ok(SingleIndex {
            index,
            writer: Mutex::new(writer),
            reader: RwLock::new(reader),
        })
    }

    fn refresh_reader(&self) -> tantivy::Result<()> {
        let new_reader = self.index.reader()?;
        *self.reader.write().unwrap() = new_reader;
        Ok(())
    }

    fn add_document(&self, title: &str, body: &str) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let mut writer = self.writer.lock().unwrap();
        let mut doc = TantivyDocument::default();
        doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("title").unwrap(), title);
        doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("body").unwrap(), body);
        writer.add_document(doc).expect("Failed to add document");
        writer.commit()?;
        self.refresh_reader()?;
        let duration = start.elapsed();
        Ok(duration)
    }

    fn add_documents(&self, documents: &Vec<(String, String)>) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let mut writer = self.writer.lock().unwrap();
        for (title, body) in documents {
            let mut doc = TantivyDocument::default();
            doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("title").unwrap(), title);
            doc.add_text(self.index.schema().get_field("body").unwrap(), body);
            writer.add_document(doc).expect("Failed to add document");
        }
        writer.commit()?;
        self.refresh_reader()?;
        let duration = start.elapsed();
        Ok(duration)
    }

    fn search(&self, query_str: &str) -> tantivy::Result<(Duration, Duration, Vec<(f32, TantivyDocument)>)> {
        let start1 = Instant::now();
        let reader = self.reader.read().unwrap();
        let duration2 = start1.elapsed();
        let searcher = reader.searcher();

        let query_parser = QueryParser::for_index(&self.index, vec![
            self.index.schema().get_field("body").unwrap(),
        ]);
        let query = query_parser.parse_query(query_str)?;

        let start = Instant::now();
        let top_docs = searcher.search(&query, &TopDocs::with_limit(10))?;
        let duration = start.elapsed();
        let mut results = Vec::new();
        for (score, doc_address) in top_docs {
            let doc = searcher.doc(doc_address)?;
            results.push((score, doc));
        }

        Ok((duration, duration2, results))
    }
}

impl MySearchEngine {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MySearchEngine {
            indexes: RwLock::new(HashMap::new()),
        }
    }

    fn get_or_create_index(&self, key: &str) -> tantivy::Result<Arc<SingleIndex>> {
        let mut indexes = self.indexes.write().unwrap();

        if let Some(index) = indexes.get(key) {
            return Ok(Arc::clone(index));
        }

        let index = SingleIndex::new()?;
        let index = Arc::new(index);
        indexes.insert(key.to_string(), Arc::clone(&index));
        Ok(index)
    }

    pub fn add_document(&self, key: &str, title: &str, body: &str) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let index = self.get_or_create_index(key)?;
        index.add_document(title, body)
    }

    pub fn add_documents(&self, key: &str, documents: &Vec<(String, String)>) -> tantivy::Result<Duration> {
        let index = self.get_or_create_index(key)?;
        index.add_documents(documents)
    }

    pub fn search(&self, key: &str, query_str: &str) -> tantivy::Result<(Duration, Duration, Vec<(f32, TantivyDocument)>)> {
        let index = self.get_or_create_index(key)?;
        index.search(query_str)
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref SEARCH_ENGINE: Arc<MySearchEngine> = {
        let engine = MySearchEngine::new();
        Arc::new(engine)
    };
}

